# Mongo DB collecting properties as a an array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am a novice in Mongo database:
I have a document in a collection, let's say with 5 properties(A,B,C,D,E). And, I have documents in the collection that contains all or some of the above properties. I want to write a query that will append the property values from all of the documents.

```
Document 1 = {Id:123, data:{A:3, B:4, C:34, D:45, E:4}}
Document 2 = {Id:123, data:{A:5, E:33}}
Document 3 = {Id:123, data:{B:499, C:24,  E:39}}
Document 4 = {Id:123, data:{A:63, B:34, C:534, D:845, E:84}}
Document 5 = {Id:123, data:{E:4}}
```

For the ID123, i want the query output to be 
Output document

```
{Id:123, A:[3,5,63], B:[4,499,34],C:[34,24,534],D:[45,845],E:[4,33,39,84,4]}
```

Comment: You can try this approach: (1) Group on the `Id` and push the `data` sub-document values into an array. Then, project to reduce (use the `$reduce` array operator) to output a single document. NOTE: there is no such format as `A:{ 3, 5, 63 }`; in MongoDB the two compound data types are sub-documents and arrays. I think you mean it as an array, like `A: [ 3, 5, 63 ]`.

Comment: Yes. my mistake. It was an array A:[3,5,63]

Comment: No need to reduce, grouping will output an unique document per Id

Comment: I get an error that the $reduce is an unknown $group operator

Comment: matthPen - I want to concatenate as per the output. COuld you please elaborate? Thanks a lot for your inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
db.getCollection('Test02').aggregate([
    {$project: {Id: 1, data: { $objectToArray: "$data" } } },
    {$unwind: {path: "$data" } },
    {$group: { _id: { "Id": "$Id", "key": "$data.k"}, data: { $push:  "$data.v"  } } },
    {$group: { _id: "$_id.Id" , data: { $push:  {k:"$_id.key", v:"$data" } } } },
    {$project: {  data: { $arrayToObject: "$data" } } },
    {$replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [  {Id: "$_id"},  "$data" ] } } }
])
```

Result:

```
{
    "Id" : 123.0,
    "E" : [ 
        4.0, 
        33.0, 
        39.0, 
        84.0, 
        4.0
    ],
    "D" : [ 
        45.0, 
        845.0
    ],
    "C" : [ 
        34.0, 
        24.0, 
        534.0
    ],
    "A" : [ 
        3.0, 
        5.0, 
        63.0
    ],
    "B" : [ 
        4.0, 
        499.0, 
        34.0
    ]
}
```

Comment: @matthPen Because it is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Simply group by Id, pushing each data field in array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$Id",
      A: {
        $push: "$data.A"
      },
      B: {
        $push: "$data.B"
      },
      C: {
        $push: "$data.C"
      },
      D: {
        $push: "$data.D"
      },
      E: {
        $push: "$data.E"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

will output exactly what you need

[Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LsWCIKco0_m)